# NSPredicate, Unable to parse the format string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nspredicate

So I am trying to get a custom object from core data by setting predicate first then querying the data. Here is what I am doing: `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dec LIKE[c] %@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[tempItemDec integerValue]]];`

So the dec is NSNumber and tempItemDec is NSString so I must first convert the string to NSInteger then wrap the integer to NSNumber to be able to query, but it get error saying this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(dec LIKE[c] %@"'
```

I am able to query items from the DB if I use their name for example, but this I can't understand?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't closed the parenthesis. Also, you need to supply a string argument for the `LIKE` operator, not a number. Use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [tempItemDec integerValue]]` for example.

Comment: I tried [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dec LIKE[c] %@)" but then I get another error.

Comment: Got it working now with @"dec == %@", but it wont work with LIKE[c] don't have idea why.

Comment: Because your argument is an `NSNumber`, not an `NSString`. `LIKE` is a string operator.